# Why does the Lewis structure for NH2 have 4 dots and not 3?

Tags: lewis-structure, valence-bond-theory, vsepr-theory

Nitrogen has 5 valence electrons.

So I would expect that when bonding with two hydrogens, two electrons would go into those bonds, and three would remain in place on the nitrogen.

Yet, [all the diagrams I see for it](https://www.sciencecoverage.com/2020/11/NH2-lewis-structure.html) look like this

[image: nh2 diagram]

**Why are there 4 dots and not 3?**

Answer (score 1):

As the compound is negatively charged, there is an extra electron present in the compound. Since the extra electron is held on nitrogen, there is 4 electrons on nitrogen instead of just 3. The extra electron will not be held on either hydrogens as it would be too unfavourable.

Comment: Why would it be negatively charged? And how do you know this in advance?

Comment: It is because in the compound you have drawn in the question, the compound is negatively charged.

Comment: I got that from the site linked

Comment: You have to start with a least some information. You either know it's an anion from whatever consideration you had before, say it's part of a compound like sodium amide and you have to draw the structure. Or you'll be given structure with the four dots and you'll have to figure out that it requires a negative charge to balance things. If none is given it would be like having ClO2 as Chlorine dioxide versus ClO2(-), the anion of the chlorous acid.